# [JavaFX-Scenebuilder][Custom Controller] Load error in Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm new to stackoverflow so if I do some mistakes, don't hesitate and tell me!

I've been working on a personnal project recently and wanted to create a GUI with specific widgets. I am working in Java using JavaFX with its GUI: scenebuilder. So far, I've been able to overcome all my issues by myself thanks to other questions asked here.
This one is about adding my own controller to my project using scenebuilder. I have created my controller (a simple Button with an overlapping ImageView [github link](https://github.com/Vincent-LAMBERT/IconedButton)) using the model found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm). As you can test, this sample app works fine. After that, I export as jar and try to add it in scenebuilder.

Here is my issue: if I don't load (line 32 of IconedButton.java) I can see my control in scenebuilder (without any display but it appears on the list) but if i do load it it disappears and I can't see it on scenebuilder. I assume my issue comes from my fxml file but it loads correctly outside scenebuilder and I have tried everything I have found about adding custom controllers in scenebuilder.
I'd like to use it after on another project and maybe adding it as a jar isn't the right way to do it but I try to do things step after step in order to understand everything.

I hope I haven't done anything wrong with this post and believe someone out there can help me!

Find here my code: [github link](https://github.com/Vincent-LAMBERT/IconedButton)
and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm) the tutorial I've followed

EDIT:

App.java:

```
package iconbutton;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var javaVersion = SystemInfo.javaVersion();
        var javafxVersion = SystemInfo.javafxVersion();

        IconedButton iconedbutton = new IconedButton();
        iconedbutton.setText("Hello!");
        
        stage.setScene(new Scene(iconedbutton));
        stage.setTitle("Iconed Button");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

IconedButton.java

```
package iconbutton;



import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * Sample custom control hosting a text field and a button.
 */
public class IconedButton extends AnchorPane {
    @FXML protected Button button;
    @FXML protected ImageView icon;

    public IconedButton() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/IconedButton.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();            
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
    
    public String getText() {
        return button.getText();
    }
    
    public void setText(String value) {
        button.setText(value);
    }
    
    public void setIcon(Image img) {
        icon.setImage(img);
    }
    
    @FXML
    protected void buttonClicked() {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked!");
    }
}
```

module-info.java:

```
module iconbutton {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    opens iconbutton to javafx.fxml;
    exports iconbutton;
}
```

IconedButton.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>

<fx:root prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="364.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <javafx.scene.layout.StackPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
          <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="icon" fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="30.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" StackPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT" />
          </children>
      </javafx.scene.layout.StackPane>
       <Button fx:id="button" onAction="#buttonClicked" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="285.0" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

EDIT2: I hava absolutely done nothing but sleep and the problem resolved itself. If you encounter the same issue just restart and pray I'd say!

Comment: Maybe it isn't enough visible but it is there. I have given you the link to the tutorial with its example and my own code on github. I'll make it more visible

Comment: read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: That's what I did. My issue isn't with the code itself but with it getting added in scenebuilder. As I said, it works as solo project and if I delete something it doesn't so it can't be considered as minimal if it doesn't work, does it?
How am I supposed to ask about this kind of issue that isn't code-related with something else than the already minimum I can give?

Comment: I have directly added the more important parts of the project but it structure itself is important too. I didn't came without any effort and tried to ofer you this minimal reproducible example from the start. I'm sorry if it is not done the way you expect, I try to do my best regarding my issue and what I have already seen around here

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by itself. Restart your PC, do something else and come back later would be my best advice!